# How to pass value to another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I am new to IOS Programming. I am sending an integer value to another view controller from segue like this:

```
SlideShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
[destViewController setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
```

I am successfully accessing this value in my SlideShowViewController.m file:

```
@synthesize selectedButton;

NSLog(@"%i",selectedButton);
```

Now I want to access  this same value which saved in selectedButton in my other View Controller. So I did this in my viewDidLoad of AnotherViewController:

```
SlideShowViewController *button= [[SlideShowViewController alloc] init];

NSLog(@"selected button is %i",button.selectedButton);
```

But I am not getting the value here.

Comment: please learn some basic OOPS concepts..

Comment: You are new to iOS programming, and you already asked THE question which leads the record of the most frequently asked question (+1 billion times). Please use the search feature ;)

Comment: When trying to pass values between 2 VCs that are not connected (by a navigation controller or tab bar controller), you can use a delegate. There are other ways as well. I would look up delegates and study it.

Comment: This question asked once per day on Stack Overflew!!!

Comment: Singletons are your friends. They are just waiting for you to get to know them better. They are lonely :(

Answer (score 0):

In the last code section, you're creating a new instance of the `SlideShowViewController`. This instance won't have the same variables as the first instance. In order to access the `selectedButton` field, you need to have a reference to your first `SlideShowViewController` instance to access its properties.

```
// Here you create a new instance. You need to hang onto the destViewController
// pointer if you want to access its selectedButton property later. This means 
// you'll need to use a global variable, or otherwise expose it in some way for
// future reference.
SlideShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
[destViewController setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
```

Later, possibly in a different method, you could do something like:

```
// Note, we're referring to destViewController using self. I'm assuming you've
// set up a property on the self object to refer to destViewController outside 
// of the scope of the initial initialization.
int selectedButtonIndex = self.destViewController.selectedButton;
```

Comment: can you please write some code or demo code so i can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

While going to second view controller do same as you did for first

```
SecondViewController *destViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController;
[destViewController2 setSelectedButton:tagIndex];
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use a hyphen in a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In your SlideShowViewController.h create a property to hold data.
In your SlideShowViewController.m synthesize property and remove

```
SlideShowViewController *button= [[SlideShowViewController alloc] init];
```

this line from SlideShowViewController.m. In this line your are creating new instance of SlideShowViewController.